# newsapi not working?Access to fetch at from origin 'null'...error in console

Tags: javascript, api

https://newsapi.org/s/google-news-api

i had just made ID and got api key 1 month ago, and now when i run this code,its shoing error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>news</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //made free seprate ID for api key and test whose API key is this
        fetch("http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey=353c319a91b44d769d3d857541d2acad", {
            "method": "GET"
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```